# Lwm2m protocol: is BootStrap server mandatory?

Tags: lwm2m

I am new to the IoT Protocols , I was reading OMA documents for Lwm2m.

I just want to understand: is LwM2M Bootstrap server mandatory? Or without that also it can work as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [the overall architecture of the LwM2M Enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hl8T.png).

The Bootstrap interface is used to provision essential information into the LwM2M Client to enable the LwM2M Client to perform the "Register" operation with one or more LwM2M Servers.

There are four bootstrap modes supported by the LwM2M Enabler:

- Factory Bootstrap
- Bootstrap from Smartcard
- Client Initiated Bootstrap
- Server Initiated Bootstrap

The LwM2M Client MUST support at least one bootstrap mode specified in the Bootstrap Interface.

In "Factory Bootstrap" mode, the LwM2M Client has been configured with the necessary bootstrap information prior to deployment of the device. The configured information may be the LwM2M Bootstrap-Server Bootstrap Information and/or the LwM2M Server Bootstrap Information. Which in turn means the LwM2M Client can connect to a LwM2M Server without prior connect to a LwM2M Bootstrap Server.

The LwM2M Bootstrap Server is not necessary if the LwM2M Client supports the Factory Bootstrap.